# Interpretation of integral

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, expected-value, integral

Does the integral below have a specific interpretation in statistics?
It looks like the marginal expectation of y, without integrating over x.
$$ \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} y f(x,y) dy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X,Y$ are cts rvs with joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Then the conditional expectation of $X$ given $Y$, denoted as $E[X|Y=y]$, is defined as

\begin{align}
E[X|Y=y] & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X|Y}(x,y) dx \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} dx \\
& = \frac{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx}{f_Y(y)},
\end{align}

and this is defined for $f_Y(y) \neq 0$. Re-arranging when $f_Y(y) \neq 0$, we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx = E[X|Y=y]f_Y(y).$$

So I guess you can think of that integral as a 'pre-normalized' conditional expectation. However, perhaps a more intuitive interpretation can be given. In particular, if you let $Y$ be discrete, then we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx = E[X|Y=y]P(Y=y),$$

which you can think of the average effect of $X$ for $Y=y$ weighted by those with $Y=y$.

Note: I flipped $X$ and $Y$ relative to your question in my response, but this should not cause any confusion hopefully.